# Excel function for two columns

Tags: excel

How do I tell Excel to:

For each "male" in colum D, take its colum J value and add it up to a sum. The function should return 12, because that's all the "male" J values added together.

I'm really stuck on this one, any suggestions would make my day. I'm new to excel and I tried googling, but it didn't yield anything useful or I didn't understand it, sadly.

[my worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC1qZ.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D1:D20="male")*(J1:J20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed! I guess I thought too much about it and didn't even consider the SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT functions.

Comment: @Vince  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the non array type formula of SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,"Male",J:J)
```